# merging two arrays to make the sum of all odd places number the largest

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem where you are given two arrays like:

```
5 3
10 12 6 14 7
1 8 2
```

it means there are 5 number in the first array, and 3 in the second array. the second line is the first array, and the third line is the second array. The goal of this program is to insert the numbers in the second array into the first ones(can be separated), and thus make the conbined array's all odd place(first,third,fifth...) number adds up to the largest possible number. Example output for the above question:

```
44
```

Since the array becomes

```
10 1 12 2 8 6 14 7
10+12+8+14=44
```

I tried to make an array out of the differences in the first array by

```
int[] diff=new int[numberinarray-1];
for(int i=0;i<numbersinarray-1;i++)
{
    diff[i]=firstarray[i]-firstarray[i+1];
}
```

and finding the places with the largest differences to insert numbers in the second array. But this way seem very uneffective and I am still unsure how to actually do this part. I wonder if there are a easier and more efficient way to do this question.

Comment: Just to check if I have understood correctly, another good way to insert the numbers would be `10 2 12 6 14 7 8 1` since the sum would still be 10 + 12 + 14 + 8 = 44? BTW you are treating the array as 1-based, where Java arrays are zero-based. For example, in my combined array 10 is in what you call the 1st place, hence it is an odd place; in Java it is at index zero.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes your way also works since it only needs to output the sum. I do undestand java array are zero-based just feel like saying it that way might be easier to understand since 0th number feels weird

Comment: This is a nice problem for dynamic programming.

Comment: Alex, I admit I'm thinking that you may want to double-check, since the problem lends itself so well to dynamic programming as @Gene is demonstrating in his answer, whether his interpretation of the rules is correct after all. Despite my comments I like the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To formulate this as a dynamic program, we can consider it as merging the two arrays from left to right. At each step, the algorithm must chose to select the head of either the first or second list. Suppose the two input sequences are `a` and `b` and let `S(i,j)` be the sum of odd-index elements in the output where `i` is the next available element of `a` and `j` is the next of `b`. Then

```
S(i,j) = if i+j is odd then max(a[i] + S(i-1,j), b[j] + S(i,j-1))
         else max(S(i-1,j), S(i,j-1)
```

Note `i+j` is the index of the output position being selected.

The base cases are

```
S(0,j) = if j is odd then b[j] + S(0,j-1) else S(0,j-1) [j>0]
S(i,0) = if i is odd then a[i] + S(i-1,0) else S(i-1,0) [i>0]
S(0,0) = max(S(0,1), S(1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on your comment (I’ve been curious to see). As far as I can tell, you will find the merging `10 1 12 6 8 2 14 7`, which gives the sum of odd places 44 as desired. However, we need not take the elements from the second array, `b`, in order, so I don’t think you are considering all solutions and may in other cases be mssing the optimum?

Comment: For example, if input arrays are `2 4` and `1 3`, I don’t think you can do better than `2 1 4 3`, sum of odd places = 6. Within the rules, I can insert the 3 from the second array at the front of the result array and get `3 2 4 1`, sum 7.